# MacOS BigSur Arduino IDE No Ports Shown

Tags: arduino-ide, mac-os

I'm trying to get the Arduino IDE (1.8.13) installed on MacOS BigSur 11.0.1 and am unable to compile and run an Arduino sketch. There are no ports available in 'Tool' menu; the port item is grayed out.  The error message states that the IDE **"Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext"**.  I have installed the following Java code:

```
java 16.0.1 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any insight would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I'm not likely to be of much use on this, but it would be good to confirm that the device shows up in /dev or whatever is in the Mac control panel that lists USB devices.  If it doesn't, then the SSL error is unrelated (which would kind of make sense) or, at a minimum, not entirely determining the problem.

Comment: @timemage serial ports are listed in /dev.

Comment: Solved: I opened Android Studio and there was a security update for Java 8 (I think) so I accepted it and installed it.  Now I can magically see serial ports in the Arduino IDE.  I wish I understood what happened, but for now the problem appears to be solved.  Thank you for allowing me to post here.

Comment: Odd.  The way the IDE comes packaged, at least for Linux and Windows, it has its own JRE bundled in.

Comment: With all the gatekeeper features on a Mac, perhaps it blocked the Java code when I downloaded the Arduino IDE?  Macs used to come with Java pre-installed, but I've read that they no longer do that.  It is a new 64 bit machine and I have to give special permission just to run my own apps developed and compiled on my old 32 bit system.

Comment: If you get to the point of having a definitive answer, it may make sense to post it *as* an answer.